# Sort options when using NEST API with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Implementing a sort in my query, how can I set IgnoreUnmapped(true) when using NEST API?
The default value is false, which means if the field doesn't exist it won't return any results, using NEST how to change the default value?

And is there any option when sorting with NEST to be able to sort with raw query? like FilterRaw()? SortRaw()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was blatantly missing in the API I just pushed support and tests for this:

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/commit/e92378589e0afaa9f6559507deb02c858d2c554d

This should make it into the next release (for future googlers next release meaning a release after 0.11.1.0).

Comment: "It's missing so I added it" definitely needs an upvote. Thanks from future googlers...